# get and add php variable in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i create one custom page in WordPress like `page-download.php`
i access this page like

```
http://example.com/download
```

its word fine but i want access this page like

```
http://example.com/download?n=skype
http://example.com/download?n=firefox
```

etc every time n value change.
and also i want get n value in page-download.php

please tell me how to do it . i know how to work in php simple but in wordpress its not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why just not use, `echo $_GET['n']` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit this page directly from the URL like below, please change your parameter, because of that I have tried same method few days ago and I can't get the parameter value.

```
http://example.com/download?from_browser=skype
http://example.com/download?from_browser=firefox
```

You can get the value like below or as per the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) :

```
$blah = get_query_var( 'from_browser');

if(isset($blah)) // Your code will be here
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply . when i try `from_browser=` in url page show but when change its like `s=` page not found whats is problem . second `$blah = get_query_var( 'from_browser');` when echo its value not printed

Comment: Because `s` is a default parameter of wordpress for search form, so we can't use for our custom parameter.

Comment: Your welcome, but the `n` parameter will be cause a issue in future when Wordpress update. Anyway as youe wish..